# How to hide arrows on numericUpDown control in win forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

to hide the arrows I have added numericUpDown.Controls[0].Hide(); and it hides the arrows but leaves white space when form is opened.

[image]

How to hide them to be like simple textBox?

Comment: why do you need to hide them..?

Comment: It's more beautiful without them

Comment: I can understand your aim, they are truely ugly and the cursor key work just as well; but I can't hide or remove them visually here. so the best option will be to put it into a label and thereby cover the right part of the nud

Comment: I just need several number fields on form for some calculations, if I use textBox I'm not very sure how to convert their values to doubles and do some calculations with them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# WinForms numericUpDown control (removing the spin box)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222601/c-sharp-winforms-numericupdown-control-removing-the-spin-box)

Answer (score 17):

You can hide the arrows by accessing the numericUpDown's `Controls` property. You can either hide or remove them:

```
numericUpDown1.Controls[0].Visible = false;
```

or

```
numericUpDown1.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
```

You can do this right after IntializeComponent().

Comment: It removes the up down buttons but still leaves with an unusable white area.

Answer (score 6):

This solution also removes the unused space:

```
public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    public MyNumericUpDown()
    {
        Controls[0].Hide();
    }

    protected override void OnTextBoxResize(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controls[1].Width = Width - 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: just in case anyone uses this, if you specify no border, you will have to add 4 instead.

Answer (score 2):

`NumericUpDown`are nice, they bring `Min, Max and Increment` values for free and hold `doubles`.

But I can understand your aim, they are truly ugly and the cursor keys work just as well without those pesky little arrows; but I can't even hide or remove them visually here.

So I think the best option will be to put the `NUD` into a smaller  `Label` and thereby cover the right part of it..

If you want to you can wrap the following workaround in a `NakedNumericUpDown` class ;-)

```
nudLabel.AutoSize = false;
nudLabel.Location = numericUpDown1.Location;
nudLabel.BorderStyle = numericUpDown1.BorderStyle;
numericUpDown1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
numericUpDown1.Controls.RemoveAt(0);  // optional
numericUpDown1.Parent = nudLabel;
numericUpDown1.Location = Point.Empty;
nudLabel.ClientSize = numericUpDown1.Size;
nudLabel.Width -= 25;  // shrink enough to cover the arrows
```

You may want to create the `Label` dynamically, of course..

One problem is that now there is no visual clue that the users can up the arrow keys to change the values, though

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code.
This code show up&down controllers, but they dont work, you use this code in Form_Load

```
YourNumericName.Controls[0].Enabled= false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom `Paint event` to draw the arrows how you want (or draw over them).

E.g.

```
    NumericUpDown nud = new NumericUpDown();
    nud.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 20f, FontStyle.Regular);
    bool isSet = false;
    NW nw = null;
    nud.Enabled = false;
    nud.VisibleChanged += delegate {
        // NUD children consist of two child windows:
        // 1) TextBox
        // 2) UpDownBase - which uses user draw
        if (!isSet) {
            foreach (Control c in nud.Controls) {
                if (!(c is TextBox)) {
                    // prevent flicker
                    typeof(Control).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, c, new object[] { true });
                    c.Paint += (sender,e) => {
                        var g = e.Graphics;
                        int h = c.Height;
                        int w = c.Width;

                        // cover up the default Up/Down arrows:
                        //g.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, 3, 3, w - 6, h/2 - 6);
                        //g.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, 3, h/2 + 3, w - 6, h/2 - 6);

                        // or hide the entire control
                        if (nud.Enabled)
                            g.Clear(nud.BackColor);
                        else
                            g.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
                    };

                    nw = new NW(c.Handle);
                    isSet = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

To ignore click events:

```
class NW : NativeWindow {

    public NW(IntPtr hwnd) {
        AssignHandle(hwnd);
    }
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            return;

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: To erase the entire buttons, then use `g.Clear(nud.BackColor);` But then you should also use a `NativeWindow` and override the `WndProc` method to ignore the `HITTEST` message. Otherwise it's possible the user clicks a button and doesn't realize it.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own numeric class. Numeric controls contains 2 controls. First textbox and second buttons. Hide first one and all your problems will be solved.

```
 public class MyCustomNumericBox : System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
    {
        public MyCustomNumericBox()
        {
           Controls[0].Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Then from toolbox get your numerir control: MyCustomNumericBox.
Or you can delete that control during constructor init and that's all

```
     public class MyCustomNumericBox : System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
    {
        public MyCustomNumericBox()
        {
           Controls.Remove(Controls[0]);
        }
    }

Full code to fit your request: 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace yournamespace
{
    class NumericBx: NumericUpDown
    {
        public NumericBx()
        {
            var ctr = Controls[0];
            this.Controls[0].Visible = false;
            this.Controls[0].Enabled = false;
            this.Controls.Remove(ctr);
            // I have tried to rewrite sizes to hide unused area...but visual studio fails to 
            //show num control. That is why this part is commented 
            //Controls[0].Size = new Size(0, ClientSize.Height);
            //Controls[1].Size = new Size(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what's the point of doing all this if the unused area is still shown as a hole in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the arrows just the reason why anyone would use numericupdown control?
If you want it to be like textbox, then use textbox. Get the functionality for keyboard up or down arrow presses intercepting the keydown event.

Comment: Intercepting the arrow key hits, validating the result. That's not somethign I want to bloat my code with. This data belongs in the UI part of the code, not in the logical part.

Comment: No, `Value`, `Minimum`, `Maximum`, etc. are. I also inherit this thing and add a custom formatter utilizing `String.Format` to add units i.e. "1.23 μW", and custom handling of NaN. When inherited as an *indicator*, the arrows are actually not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but you can use a panel in the Form Designer and set the BackColor property to white and cover the arrows.

Of course this creates a white area where the user cannot interact with the control, so I recommend covering the NumericUpDown's borders and drawing a line on the left edge of the panel. (Looks something like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoGGr.png) in the designer).

Then, add a Paint event to the panel:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(174, 173, 179), 1))
  {
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 0, panel1.Height);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but no one has solved it satisfactorily.
And here is mine solution:

1. Create a new "CustomControl"
2. Change CustomControl to NumericUpDown
3. Add an OnResize overridee

   ```
   public partial class nNumeric : NumericUpDown
   {
       public nNumeric()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
       protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
       {
           var buttons = this.Controls[0];
           var edit = this.Controls[1];
           buttons.Visible = false;
           edit.MinimumSize = new Size( Width - edit.Left*2, 0);
           edit.Width = this.Width;
       }
   }
   ```
4. done, simple and effective :)

I hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick-and-dirty 3-line workaround for that:

```
int widthOfSpinButtons = this.numericUpDown.Controls[0].Width; // store width of spin buttons before removing them
this.numericUpDown.Controls[0].Dispose(); // remove spin buttons; after this, the first item left in the list of controls is the UpDownEdit control (the texbox)
this.numericUpDown.Controls[0].MinimumSize = new Size(this.numericUpDown.Controls[0].Width + widthOfSpinButtons, this.numericUpDown.Controls[0].MinimumSize.Height); // increase the minimum width of the UpDownEdit (the textbox) to its current width plus the width of the removed spin buttons
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution:change the input type from number to tel
**input type="tel"**

Comment: Windows Forms, not HTML.