# How to restrict text box to positive only numbers with Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Working on a discount field. The field needs to only allow positive numbers between 0 and 100. Field is a text box. Using visual studio and visual basic.

Comment: This could be done in a number of ways, several of which are in the top 10 Google results for "Visual Basic textbox positive numbers."  Did you try any of those?

Comment: To be honest I don't understand the IsNumeric part, and none of them show how to deny negative numbers. 

Private Sub txtDiscount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDiscount.TextChanged
       
 If txtDiscount.Text < 0 Then
            MsgBox("Discount needs to be positive")
        End If
    End Sub

That's what I've got so far.

Comment: Use a [**`NumericUpDown`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. It is limited to numbers only and you can customize the range, display, decimal numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `NumericUpDown` control along with its Minimum, Maximum, and DecimalPlaces properties.

However, if you don't like the scroll box and really want to use a `TextBox`, it can be done like this:

```
Private min As Decimal = 1
Private max As Decimal = 100

Private Sub txtDiscount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDiscount.TextChanged
    Dim i As Decimal
    Static lastValidText = ""
    If (txtDiscount.Text = "") OrElse (Decimal.TryParse(txtDiscount.Text, i) AndAlso (i >= min And i <= max)) Then
        lastValidText = txtDiscount.Text
    Else
        txtDiscount.Text = lastValidText
        txtDiscount.SelectionStart = txtDiscount.TextLength
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim min As Decimal = 0.00
        Dim max As Decimal = 100.0
        Dim i As Decimal
        Static lastValidText = ""
        If Decimal.TryParse(txtDiscount.Text, i) AndAlso (i >= min And i <= 
     max) Then
            lastValidText = txtDiscount.Text
        Else
            txtDiscount.Text = lastValidText
            txtDiscount.SelectionStart = txtDiscount.TextLength

        End If
    End Sub

That's what I got to. My only issue is that I can't erase all the characters, as in if I put in 100 it only erases back to 1.

And sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Right! Didn't test all edge cases. Fixed in my answer.

Comment: you should move this to keypressed event. you can evaluate the value before the key is inserted to the textbox. If the value is invalid then e.keychar="" or change the value of the textbox to the max value or min value depending if the user was trying -5 or 105

Comment: @Chillzy then it wouldn't work with mouse clicks i.e. drag-drop or right-click paste. Though I'm not sure if it's a requirement (but I did consider it either way).

Comment: a drag and drop has to be programmed to work so it should be an issue. I never tried a right click paste to see which events get trigger. Nicely done but I wasn't sure why go so far but great answer.

Comment: Pretty easy question, (though the quality is debatable) but it's holiday season so why not.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help!

Comment: @djv : Actually there [are workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6222646) to remove the scroll box/spinbox of a `NumericUpDown`. Neat textbox-solution you made though!

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks. I've seen that solution, but it has a blank space where the scrollers were. I've made my own by subclassing TextBox and adding a numeric Value, Min, and Max properties and a Format (i.e. for engineering units and decimal places). Too big for this forum though :)